# Are there any unary algorithms that are really faster than binary ones?

Tags: algorithms, computer-science, computational-complexity

I'm doing a lot of reading on the unary number system, and couldn't really find any real any algorithms for which the unary system is faster than the binary system.

For example, the prime factorization problem is linear in the unary system, which is a well known fact. However, this is only a trick. As with unary we call $N$ the number we wish to factor, but in the binary problem $N$ is the number of bits. So essentially, the unary system (to adjust for binary) really goes from $O(N)$ to $O(2^N)$.

Is there any problem that is legitimately faster, when adjusting for size, for the unary numerals over the binary numerals?

Comment: Adding 1 is $O(1)$ for a unary number and $O(\log n)$ for a binary number. Same for subtracting 1.

Comment: @MarkSaving I am probably missing something, but why isn't adding 1 $O(1)$ in binary as well?

Comment: Because to add 1 to $2^n - 1$, you will need to do a total of $n$ carries.

Comment: Shouldn't that be $O(n)$, actually? Because the input is measured by the length of the input? Oh, that's a good example anyway. Thank you.

Comment: You asked for an example “adjusting for size” between the two.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4508471/14578, https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/51783/5038.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Comment: Adding $1$ in unary is not $O(1)$, but $O(n)$ (or $O(2^n)$ if $n$ is the length in binary): you first need to move the head to the end of the number, and only then you can write a new digit.